# Accidentally installed a Node tutorial to WINDOWS/system32

Tags: windows-8

Total noob. Took one one or two classes on python and html/css/js in school and have tried to continue getting to a point where I can consistently work in one console. I was installing node on Windows 8 and having issues with the windows npm that comes with the node msi. Well, i got it to work, but forgot to cd, so i installed the learnyounode tutorial package for node to C:\WINDOWS\system32 How do I undo this noob screw up? Should I even?

Much thanks.

Comment: Extract the files to another folder then find each file in the wrong folder and delete it

Comment: Best way is to sort the system32 folder contents by "date created", should make it easier to find all the files.

Comment: @Moab: Might work but not always because some installers that extract files from an archive will result in files with their original creation dates so they may still get mixed up with newer files already in that folder.